# How to `Manipulate[]` Particles in a Box

Tags: plotting

so here is a set of data. [set_of_particles_data](http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/data.dat)

here is the code with return some error. it said cannot combine the Graphics. first i copy and paste the data and save it as data.txt.

how can i combine the graphics and `Manipulate[]` it?. thank you

```
dataparticle = ToExpression[Import["Data.txt", "Data"]];
nlast = Length[dataparticle];

    L = 1;
    coordinates[1] = {0, 0};
    coordinates[2] = {0, L};
    coordinates[3] = {L, L};
    coordinates[4] = {L, 0};
    coordinates[5] = {0, 0};

    (*First, generate the box*)
    glbox = Graphics[Line[{Table[coordinates[n], {n, 1, 5}]}], 
      AspectRatio -> 1]
    (*Box Done*)

    (*Frame 1 consist of 10 pair of coordinates of 10 particle*)
    dataparticle[[1]]

    (*Extract the Particle coordinate*)
    particlesframe1 = dataparticle[[1]];


    (*put it inside the box*)
    t1 = Graphics[Point[particlesframe1]];
    Show[t1, glbox]

    (*manipulate it*)
    mpl = Manipulate[Graphics[Point[dataparticle[[n]]]], {n, 1, nlast}];
    Show[mpl, glbox]
```

Here is Sample of Data to test.

```
dataparticle[[1]] (*10 (particles) pair of coordinate for first frame*)
{{0.155769, 0.666253}, {0.242599, 0.951033}, {0.140918, 
  0.998855}, {0.534282, 0.504708}, {0.501699, 0.514544}, {0.745021, 
  0.519584}, {0.569252, 0.833331}, {0.346653, 0.902298}, {0.185735, 
  0.923443}, {0.671453, 0.398735}}

dataparticle[[2]] (*10 (particles) pair of coordinate for second frame*)
{{0.15519, 0.664599}, {0.238626, 0.966334}, {0.135778, 
  0.987197}, {0.54808, 0.488902}, {0.509371, 0.504458}, {0.748664, 
  0.537637}, {0.553474, 0.833039}, {0.354848, 0.906704}, {0.17907, 
  0.933902}, {0.67099, 0.405}}

dataparticle[[3]] (*10 (particles) pair of coordinate for third frame*)
{{0.154611, 0.662944}, {0.234653, 0.981635}, {0.130638, 
  0.97325}, {0.561879, 0.473097}, {0.517042, 0.494371}, {0.752307, 
  0.55569}, {0.537696, 0.832746}, {0.363043, 0.911111}, {0.172405, 
  0.944361}, {0.670526, 0.411264}}
```

and up to to `dataparticle[[5000]]` (*the 5000th frame*)

image below shows the first frame of 10 particles. i wish to manipulate it until 5000th frame like the code i wrote but return error.

[image: first frame]

Comment: Comments are delimited by `(*  *) `. Please edit your post accordingly,  as otherwise the current  strings may cause undesirable  side-effects during evaluation. It would also be better if you hardcoded some sample points into the question to make it self-contained and easy to test.

Comment: you mean put some data? @YvesKlett

Comment: Yes, some inlined sample data to get rid of the cumbersome (and potentially unsafe) download / import steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 L = 1;
nlast = Length[dataparticle];
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}]}],
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[#]}] & /@ 
    Take[dataparticle, 10 n]
   }],
 {{n, 1, nlast/10}}
 ]
```

[image]

Have fun!